# Using whenjs with requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, when-js

I am unable to use requirejs with whenjs, it gives 404 errors about missing files when running the site. I'm following the instructions in the [whenjs README](https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/2.5.1/README.md):

Firstly, I run `git submodule add https://github.com/cujojs/when` when in the project root dir.

Then I do "Configure your loader with a package" in `app/public/js/main.js`:

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: "js",
  packages: [
    {
      name: "when",
      path: "../../../when",
      main: "when"
    }
  ]
});
```

This leaves the following directory layout:

```
project-root/
  app/
    public/
      js/
        main.js
        helpers/
          myhelper.js
  when/
```

The file (`myhelper.js`) that requires whenjs has:

```
define(['when'], function(When) {
```

This produces the error

`GET http://localhost:4580/js/when/when.js 404 (Not Found)`

I tried copying the js files from `project-root/when` into `app/public/js/libs/when`

```
project/
  app/
    public/
      js/
        main.js
        helpers/
          myhelper.js
        libs/
          when/
```

and using the following code:

```
//main.js
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: "js",
  packages: [
    {
      name: "when",
      path: "libs/when",
      main: "when"
    }
  ]
});

//myhelper.js
define(['when'], function(When) {
```

Produces the same error:

`GET http://localhost:4580/js/when/when.js 404 (Not Found)`

It appears that whatever is in `myhelper.js` is ignoring the `packages` declaration - I'm not sure if there's something else I'm supposed to do there? The whenjs instructions don't say to.

I tried this:

```
//main.js
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: "js",
  packages: [
    {
      name: "when",
      path: "libs/when",
      main: "when"
    }
  ],
  paths: {
    w: "./libs/when"
  }
});

//myhelper.js
define(['w/when'], function(When) {
```

This doesn't produce and error - although I haven't tried using the library with it yet…

The version of Requirejs is v2.1.8, and I've read [the API instructions regarding packages but I'm none the wiser](http://www.requirejs.org/docs/api.html#packages). What is it that means the whenjs instructions don't work here? I've tried other combinations of settings too, like combining the `paths` and `packages` options but to no avail.

This is not a Node or javascript only project, so a drastic movement of directories is not an option.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I've really no idea why I got a down vote for this. Please remember to add a comment with a down vote - the whole point is to encourage *better* questions, so give a hint about what needs changed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `paths` property of `requirejs.config`:
If you put `when.js` under `js/libs/when/when.js`, you can try:

```
    requirejs.config({
        paths: {
            'when': 'libs/when/when'
        }
    });
define(['when'], function(When) {...
```

You don't even need the `baseUrl`, if your JavaScript tag contains it, but you can specify it if you want.

This should solve the library load issue, but if when.js does not support AMD, you can add a `shim` to the configuration:

```
shim: {
    'when': {
        exports: 'When'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. I'm fairly certain whenjs must support AMD as it's in their instructions, which is why I find this strange :/